# Security Warnings в FreePBX

Tags: linux, asterisk

Постоянно появляется предупреждение об изменении конфига extensions.conf.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что я его и редактирую вручную, не через FreePBX, так как руками прописать екстеншн удобнее. Каким образом мне текущие изменения в конфиге санкционировать, а затем сделать так, что бы последующие не были санкционированы и вылазил такой варнинг?

CentOS 6.5 сборка FreePBX Distro - FreePBX 12, Asterisk 11.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*freepbx* хранит **описание** конфигурации *asterisk-а* в базе данных.

через web-интерфейс *freepbx* вы изменяете только это **описание** в базе данных.

сам же *asterisk* при (пере-)запуске читает свою **конфигурацию** из файлов каталога `/etc/asterisk`.

а после нажатия в web-интерфейсе *freepbx* кнопки «apply configuration changes» на основании **описания** строится **конфигурация** *asterisk-а* — т.е., перезаписываются (при необходимости) файлы в каталоге `/etc/asterisk`, а программе *asterisk* даётся сигнал перечитать конфигурацию.

---

насколько мне известно, «обратный» процесс — парсинг конфигурации *asterisk-а*, хранящейся в каталоге `/etc/asterisk`, и внесение изменений в **описание**, хранящееся в базе данных — во *freepbx*, увы, не реализован.

поэтому все внесённые вами вручную изменения в конфигурацию *asterisk-а* будут утеряны при перезаписи исправленного вами файла. о чём вас, собственно, и предупреждает web-интерфейс *freepbx*.

---

если вам проще изменять непосредственно конфигурацию *asterisk-а*, вероятно, имеет смысл отказаться от использования *freepbx* — ведь он не умеет обновлять своё **описание** на основе внесённых вами вручную изменений в **конфигурацию** *asterisk-а*.

Comment: Я транки добавлял через PBX, Incoming/Outcomming route, extensions при этом оставался не тронутым. Он переписывает только те файлы на которые непосредственно влияет конфигурация?

Comment: перезаписываются лишь те файлы, которые необходимо изменить для применения внесённых в **описание** (читай — базу данных *freepbx*) изменений.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо)